# How do I get such a stereogram?

Tags: inkscape, vector

[image]

The picture above is from this paper. https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1291291/FULLTEXT01.pdf

I think this picture is better than what I have painted before, because it feels more specific. How can I draw such a box?

The schematics in some papers are very good. They should use a vector diagram. Can I copy this diagram from their paper? Then I make changes on it.

I want the cuboid on the picture and such bars.
[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You legally can't copy the work of anyone else without their expressed permission in much of the world. Ethically, it's just poor practice. Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/147606/edit) to provide more detail about what exactly you are wanting? Is it the bevel and emboss effect on the boxes?That's *not* vector. The type? The rounded corners? The dashed border?

Comment: Its best not to think about vector images as painting. The core principle behind vector engines more resemble cutting than painting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not trying to copy his pictures completely. I just want some graphics on it to draw my pictures. For example, the above rectangular parallelepiped and the strip connecting several rectangular parallelepipeds. This looks more three-dimensional than my previous ones. I intercepted the elements I wanted in the question.

Comment: I'm not an Inkscape user, but bevel and emboss (which is what you are referring to) is traditionally not great with vector image because the effect is often raster in nature.... but see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwDO1REx1zU

Comment: It's not a stereogram. The apparent thickness is either drawn or added by inserting effects. Term stereogram is generally used to present images which has separate views for both eyes. Many of us are able to watch them so that the 3D illusion occurs. Your left and right halves cannot be the parts of a stereogram because they have mirrored orientations and different contents. See some stereograms for example here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109510/how-to-make-stereogram-using-photoshop-or-any-other-adobe-software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Inkscape you can stack elements to get something which at least resembles the wanted structure. You can get the smooth gradients by inserting blur. The number of stacked elements is high, but you hopefully learn soon how to make copies and edit them. The parts of the stacked elements an be accessed in the Objects panel, no matter they are inside groups or have clipping paths.

An example:

[image]

The button in the left is a group of three elements. The group is ungrouped and the parts are moved apart in the right.

On the top there's 2 simpler buttons which are otherwise identical but have different sizes. In the bottom there's a blurred rounded rectangle which makes the dark edge shadows which can be seen in the top edge and in the bottom edge.

The buttons are themselves groups and they have a clipping path to restrict the blur. One button is dissassembled in the next image:

[image]

The blue shape is the clipping path. It's inserted to the rest parts by selecting all and applying Object > Clip > Set

The rest of the parts are a group which contains three elements. They are ungrouped and moved apart in the right.

On the top theres a blurred rounded rectangle. Blur makes the edges of the parts below visible.

In the middle there's a brighter version for highlight and in the bottom there's a dark version for shadow. all parts have a little different sizes and they are moved a little apart to make the highlight and the shadow occur at the right sides.

This is complex when compared to Bevel&Emboss effect which makes the simpler button with a couple of clicks. That effect is available in Photoshop and Affinity series. GIMP has an alternative: Bump.

Actually also Inkscape has its own version as SVG path filter but adjusting SVG path filters is so tricky that I skip it.